# What is this commutative diagram for continuity?

Tags: continuity, category-theory, definition

The "Homological cohomology memes" facebook page [recently posted](https://www.facebook.com/trivialbycategorytheory/photos/a.995720553801240.1073741827.995710787135550/1513384782034812/?type=3&theater) an image, copied below.

In the 4th panel, there are maps from $c$ into $\mathbb{R}$, from $\ell_\infty$ into $\mathbb{R}$, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and $A_f: c \to \ell_\infty$. What are these maps?

[image]

**Panel 1:** [$\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit)

**Panel 2:** [sequential continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences)

**Panel 3:** [topological continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces)

**Panel 4:** ???

**Panel 5:** [continuous functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/continuous+functor)

Comment: might this just be the definition in terms of sequences? $f$ continuous if for all convergent sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ (with $x_n \rightarrow x$), we have $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$?

Comment: I think @slin0 is right, but this definition is very flawed, since it is a priori not true that $A_f$ (apply $f$ to the sequence) takes a convergent sequence to a bounded sequence.

Comment: @MooS: sure it is 'a priori true', just you haven't proven it yet, but it's just as much of a problem to discuss `c` (i.e. the space of convergent sequences) without characterizing continuity, either. the [original paper](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~sar323/exposition/continuity.pdf) takes the conventional definition for granted and then shows their equivalence, fyi

Comment: @oldrinb That paper you linked answers the question, I think. Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: This was posted  by @Trivbycategorytheory as an answer because he had not enough reputation to post a comment:  Only posting for context. For panel 4, the thought was simply "continuity through commutative diagram". Indeed, the definition we used was that found in the link posted by oldrinb. I'm not sure if it is a standard definition as I haven't encountered it.